# How to print out the name of the variable and its value to browser?

Tags: php

I have just started learning PHP, so please forgive me for asking a question like this.

I have a variable `$myVar = "hello";` and I want to print out the name of the variable and its value to the browser.

I tried

```
echo "$myVar: $myVar"; //this simple prints out the value of $myVar twice
```

also tried

```
echo '$myVar'+ ":$myVar"; //somehow the number 0 was printed out to the browser
```

also tried

```
echo '$myVar: $myVar'; //this just prints out the string literal itself
```

I understand the difference between double quotes and single quotes, but just can't seem to get this simple example working.

Comment: Do this: `echo "\$myVar: $myVar";`

Comment: thank you sir! that was easy lol really appreciate your help!

Comment: Glad I could help. Now write an answer and accept it to close the question, otherwise it would be floating around as *open* question.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul you could do that too :)

Comment: @RobbieAverill Okay, just did. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
echo "\$myVar: $myVar";
```

Use backslash `\` to display the variable name as it is.